# Scalability of reactive programming

Tags: scalability, reactive

If reactive programming is avoiding threads and use instead asynchronous message passing between objects, how is managed the scalability?

How decide when a new instance is needed?
Is there some api that manages this transparently?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Reactive Manifesto](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org#elastic):

> "Reactive Systems can react to changes in the input rate by increasing
>   or decreasing the resources allocated to service these inputs."

If the components are isolated from eachother and don't share resources, they can be replicated - i.e. you can run multiple instances of a component at once and split the inputs between them.

This is possible because the inputs take the form of asynchronous messages. From any one instance's perspective, it only has to deal with the message(s) it receives. It doesn't care about the ordering of a message in relation to other messages, nor about how other instances are dealing with their messages.

So you can have as many (scaled up) or as few (scaled down) instances of a component running at once as needed, and because they're all independently receiving different messages - i.e. different parts of the problem - they won't conflict, double-up on or compete with eachother. This property of upwards or downwards scalability is referred to as "elasticity".

There are a number of libraries, frameworks and APIs that can help you to implement a reactive system, such as scaling of components in response to workload, as long as you correctly configure them and use the constructs they give you. The biggest one at the moment seems to be the [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/) API, encompassing RxJS, RxJava and other platform-specific frameworks.

Note: Reactive programming isn't necessarily against threads - only against threads which compete for shared resources. If you decouple threads from eachother, for example, by splitting up a workload and distributing different parts of it to different threads, that's a form of [replication](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/glossary#Replication), a technique endorsed by reactive programming.